# How to move text with the wheel in the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, html5-canvas

I now want to place text on the spikes inside the wheel and I need them to rotate the with the wheel as well. Also these number of spikes can change.I am unable to do this as I am just starting with html.
The part where I am having trouble is how to detect the number of spikes in the wheel dynamically.And how to place the `p` tags dynamically over spikes and then move them with the wheel?

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: As its image so you cant detect anything inside image without [imageprocessing](https://sisu.ut.ee/imageprocessing/book/1) You can do this if your image wont change, mean every time there are 7 spikes.

Comment: okay suppose we have say 7 spikes only, then how can we place text on each spike and make it rotate.

Comment: Yes this is possible i can show you this example in a while

Comment: Do let me know if you got any issue regarding to ans below

Answer (score 2):

As discussion in comments

> Posted my answer with pure CSS

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 0 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1d1f20;
}

.wheel {
  width:255px;
   height:255px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-animation: rotation 4s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

.wheel span{
 position: absolute;
}
span.fir {
    top: 45px;
    left: 122px;
}
span.sec {
    top: 75px;
    right: 62px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
span.thi {
    top: 135px;
    right: 51px;
    transform: rotate(101deg);
}
span.frt {
    top: 190px;
    right: 92px;
    transform: rotate(-230deg);
}
span.fiv {
    top: 190px;
    left: 92px;
    transform: rotate(-136deg);
}
span.six {
    top: 135px;
    left: 51px;
    transform: rotate(-111deg);
}
span.svn {
    top: 75px;
    left: 62px;
    transform: rotate(-52deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wheel" >
<img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/car-wheel-2-827505.png">
 <span class="fir">hi</span>
 <span class="sec">hi</span>
 <span class="thi">hi</span>
 <span class="frt">hi</span>
 <span class="fiv">hi</span>
 <span class="six">hi</span>
 <span class="svn">hi</span>
</div>
```

**You can change image and then change values its as per view**

Comment: Thanks @Awais for the answer. I was able to achieve the css part but wasn't sure that whether it was optimal solution. Also the animation part is big learning for me.

Comment: No problem. a simple logic is i just stick the text with css rotation and then move that img in which text is a part of that img....